# Clarification of the claim 3 in the proof of the irrationality of $\pi ^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am reading Laczkovich's proof ([can be found here:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Laczkovich's_proof))

Let $f_k(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}k+\frac{x^4}{2! k(k+1)}-\frac{x^6}{3! k(k+1)(k+2)} + \cdots \qquad (k\notin\{0,-1,-2,\ldots\})$

Claim 3: If $x\neq 0$ and if $x^2$ is rational, then $(\forall k\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}):f_k(x)\neq0\text{ and }\frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}\notin\mathbb{Q}.$

And there is this part that I didn't understand:

When he proves this claim he starts with..
Otherwise, there would be a number $y\neq 0$ and integers $a$ and $b$ such that $f_{k}(x)=ay$ and $f_{k+1}(x)=by$. In order to see why, take $y=f_{k+1}(x)$, $a=0$ and $b=1$ if $f_{k}(x)=0$; otherwise, choose integers $a$ and $b$ such that ${f_{k+1}(x)\over f_{k}(x)}={b\over a}$ and define $y= {f_{k}(x)\over a}={f_{k+1}(x)\over b}$. $(*)$

first of all does he assume here that $f_k(x)=0\text{ and }\frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}\in\mathbb{Q}?$
When he writes this "there would be a number $y\neq 0$ and integers $a$ and $b$ such that $f_{k}(x)=ay$ and $f_{k+1}(x)=by$ "is it because he assumes what if 
$\frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}\in\mathbb{Q}?$ but does he also assume that what if $f_k(x)=0\text ?$

I mean what he is doing here is the use of contrapositive of the claim3?
I just want to know how is the process of thinking made here. Can someone explain/paraphrase the reasoning in $(*)?$ I am literally stuck there. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is answered in the sentence "In order to see why ...".

Comment: If we say "suppose $x$ is a rational number, then $x={a \over b}$ ,where $a\in\mathbb Z , b\in\mathbb Z -\{0\}$ .Otherwise, $x\neq {a \over b}$" I want to see something like this. Against which sentence this "otherwise,there would be a number y..." statement is made? @NikWeaver

Comment: As a general rule of thumb undergraduate questions are more appropriate for mathematics.stackexchange.com  This site is aimed at professional mathematicians and graduate students.

Comment: I didn't know that, I will keep this in mind, thanks @NoahSnyder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arnaud is correct, and here is a fleshed-out version of the start of the proof of the claim.

Assume the claim is false.

Then for some $x\neq0$ with $x^2$ rational, there exists $k\in\mathbb Q\setminus \{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$ for which either $f_k(x)=0$ or $\dfrac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}\in\mathbb Q$. Fix such $x$ and $k$.

Case 1: ($f_k(x)=0$): Taking $y=f_{k+1}$, $a=0$, and $b=1$, we have $f_k(x)=ay$ and $f_{k+1}(x)=by$ for some integers $a$ and $b$ and real $y$.

Case 2: ($f_k(x)\neq0$): Then $\dfrac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}\in\mathbb Q$ (because the claim is false), so choose integers $a$ and $b$ so that $\dfrac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}=\dfrac{b}{a}$, and let $y=\dfrac{f_{k}(x)}{a}$. Again, we have $f_k(x)=ay$ and $f_{k+1}(x)=by$ for some integers $a$ and $b$ and real $y$.

In case 2, $y\neq0$ is clear, but in either case, $y=\dfrac{f_{k+1}(x)}b$, and if $y=0$, it would follow from claim 1 that $f_{k+n}(x)=0$ for all integers $n\geq1$, in which case the limit in claim 2 would not hold.

Thus $y\neq0$, and summarizing so far: if claim 3 is false (as witnessed by fixed $k$ and $x$), there are integers $a$ and $b$ and real $y\neq0$ for which $f_k(x)=ay$ and $f_{k+1}(x)=by$.

Now recall that $x^2$ is rational, and (remembering that $k$ is rational and $a$ and $b$ are integers) choose $c\in\mathbb N$ such that $bc/k$, $ck/x^2$, and $c/x^2$ are all integers. Then consider the sequence $g_n$ [and so on…]

Comment: This is a great answer that solved my doubts! Thanks a lot, I was thinking about this for two days, but got nowhere.

Comment: Glad to help! The write-up you linked to was definitely bare-bones and not as clear as it might have been.

Comment: Indeed it is. By the way does the choice of $b$ in case 1 really matter? What if I didn't assign any value to $b$ and only take $a=0$ and write the rest as you did?

Comment: I don’t know if $b=1$ was needed — I didn't think that detail through once I patched up what was written. ;)

Comment: can you please look at one more [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590933/laczkovichs-proof-of-the-irrationality-of-pi-2) that I have about this proof? @SteveKass

Comment: I added an answer to your other question.

Answer (score 2):

> first of all does he assume here that $f_k(x)=0$ **and** $\frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

No, there is no logical mistake here, he assumes $\ldots$ **or** $\ldots $, and depending on which of these two holds the value of $a$ and $b$ will be different. See

> $a=0$ and $b=1$ $\underline{\smash{\text{if }f_k(x)=0}};\ \underline{ \text{otherwise}}\ldots$

The only slight inaccuracy that is made by the author here is that $f_{k+1}(x)$ might be $0$, in which case $b$ has to be $0$, and everything works fine except the equation $y=\frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{b}$ doesn't make sense any more, but this is not a big deal since all you really need is $f_{k+1}(x)=by$.

Hope that makes sense...